# how to Cache json data and display in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, caching

I am trying to Cache JSON data, everything in my code is working fine, but the problem is I don't want to request getting the data from api and display it every time, which makes the app very slow, so I want to Cache data on the device and updated every week. i dont know how to do that, please help.

here is my code

```
 class AnimalJoke extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimalJoke({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AnimalJokeState createState() => _AnimalJokeState();
}

class _AnimalJokeState extends State<AnimalJoke> {
  Future getData() async {
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("https://here is endpont api"),
    );
    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print('connected succsefully');
    return responsebody;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text("طرائف عن الحيوانات"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List snap = snapshot.data;

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("error"),
              );
            }
return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snap.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  " ${snap[index]['joke']}",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  " ${snap[index]['answer']}",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              );
            });
      },
    ),
  ),


  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways,
One is using your data in local DB and another one is using dio cache library [Library Link](https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http_cache). Please check the details in the library documentation.

```
   Dio().get(
  "http://www.google.com",
  options: buildCacheOptions(Duration(days: 7)),
);
```

Comment: where should i put these line in my code ? i read this library but int not clear to me , so just these line can help my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to save data to your phone once the api has done loading. You can also save a date/time when the api data was loaded. Check your shared preference data everytime the app is ran with current system date n time. If one week has passed, delete shared pref data and recall api to load list. Hope it's clear